# Can't use a variable with tar command in script

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I wrote a simple script in nano like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
tar --create --verbose --bzip2 --file=myfile.tbz ~/test
```

It works fine.

But then i wrote the same script using a variable and now it gives me an error:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Backup which directory?"
read $dir
tar --create --verbose --bzip2 --file=myfile.tbz $dir
```

So i input ~/test when prompted and this time i get:

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of `read $dir` you have to write `read dir`, that's it. Reference: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/bash-read#arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a varibale with wrong syntax. The read prompt will not take $dir as a variable, use only dir instead of $dir with the read command. Below is the current syntax.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Backup which directory?"
read dir
tar --create --verbose --bzip2 --file=myfile.tbz $dir
```